# Regex to match spaces and apostrophes

Tags: regex

I need a Regex that matches all instances of any character that is not a-z (space and things like apostrophes need to be selected). Sorry for the noob factor.

//novice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is regex that will literally match any char that is not a-z. The `/g` flag indicates a global match which will cover *all* instances of the match.

```
/[^a-z]+/g
```

If you need uppercase letters too, you can either pass the `/i` flag which indicates case insensitivity:

```
/[^a-z]+/gi
```

or include the uppercase chars in character class:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+/g
```

Comment: This will also match no character at all.

Answer (score 2):

With a somewhat sophisticated regex engine (grep will do just fine) this will be quite general:

```
/[^[:lower:]]+/
```

(Note the ^!)

The difference between `[:lower:]` and `[a-z]` is that the former should be I18N friendly and match e.g. ü, â etc.

For case insensitive matching use `[:alpha:]`, to also include digits use `[:alnum:]`. `[:alnum:]` differs from `\W` in that it doesn't include _ (underscore).

Note that character classes written in this style may be combined as usual (like `a-z` etc.), e.g. `[^[:lower:][:digit:]]+` would match a non-empty string of characters not including any lowercase letters or digits.

Answer (score 1):

The character class `[^a-zA-Z]` will match any character that isn't (upper or lowercase) a-z.

I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: thanks! this one works for the preg_replace in php, and Asaphs version worked for the duplicate one i was using in Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

\W will match any non-alphanumeric (a-z, 0-9, and underscore) character.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression matches any letter other than `[a-z]`:

```
/[^a-z]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.

1. /[^a-z]+/ will match anything other than lowercase letters.
2. /[^A-Za-z]+/ will match anything non-alpha.
3. /\W+/ on most systems will match non-'word' characters. Word characters include A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and '_' (underscore). Note that that is an uppercase W.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to create another regex [try reading this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Teaching to fish and all that. :)